# Connect to an input variable slice in OpenMDAO 2?

Tags: openmdao

I'm trying to connect a smaller sized output variable of one component to a specific slice of an input variable in another. The reverse is possible (connecting  a slice of a larger output to a smaller input) via the src_indices keyword such as in the example below.

```
import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om

p = om.Problem()

p.model.add_subsystem('C1', om.AddSubtractComp('y', 'x', vec_size=3,
                                               units=None, desc='', var_set=''))
p.model.add_subsystem('C2', om.AddSubtractComp('y', 'x', vec_size=2,
                                               units=None, desc='', var_set=''))

p.model.connect('C1.y', 'C2.x', src_indices=[0, 1])

p.setup()
p.run_model()

print(p['C2.y'])
```

However, what if I wanted to instead connect C2.y to C1.x[0:2]? It seems that there should be a "target indices" keyword to mirror src_indices, but I haven't found anything. I've tried this:

```
p.model.connect('C2.y', 'C1.x', src_indices=[0, 1, 0])
```

and it works, but now I've got y[0] connected to x[2] which isn't desired. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: OpenMDAO2 doesn't support target indices.  You'll have to Mux several inputs together using MuxComp:  http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/mux_demux_comps.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenMDAO 2 unfortunately doesn't support the connection of an output to some subset of an input.  As a workaround, you could create an 'adapter' component that takes the smaller array as an input and outputs a larger array.  For example:

```
import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om

p = om.Problem()

p.model.add_subsystem('C2', om.AddSubtractComp('y', 'x', vec_size=2, units=None, desc=''))
p.model.add_subsystem('Adapter', om.ExecComp('y[:2]=x', x=np.zeros(2), y=np.zeros(3)))
p.model.add_subsystem('C1', om.AddSubtractComp('y', 'x', vec_size=3, units=None, desc=''))

p.model.connect('C2.y', 'Adapter.x')
p.model.connect('Adapter.y', 'C1.x')

p.setup()

p['C2.x'] = 5.

p.run_model()

print(p['C2.y'])
print(p['C1.y'])
```

Comment: Thanks Bret. Just out of curiosity, is there a systemic reason that can't be done, or just a feature that hasn't been built in yet?

Comment: In theory `target_indices` could be implemented. We've discussed it before, but it does add quite a bit of error checking and setup overhead. These are both things we'd like to avoid, and the need for target indices hasn't come up often enough to warrant it yet. 

Perhaps in the future....